# QGIS - Trigger's execution too slow (QGIS freeze)

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, trigger

I am currently working on a SpatiaLite layer that is updated after insertions and modifications through triggers.

When I copy-paste features on the **"HABITATS_POLY"** layer, it triggers updates on another layer (**"GESTION_CODES"**). The results from this second layer are then utilized to update the original layer, effectively completing the process in three steps.

**Unfortunately, I'm encountering a significant performance issue during this sequence. QGIS experiences extreme slowness and, in some cases, freezes entirely.**

Despite my attempts to optimize the triggers in various ways, I'm still grappling with the challenge. I think that the root cause may lie in the systematic search for codes across the entire GESTION_CODES table. While this table typically contains up to a maximum of a hundred rows, and often fewer, the repetitive nature of this search hundreds of times could be contributing to the slowdown.

I haven't identified an alternative approach that meets my requirements and resolves the performance issue.

Hereafter, the triggers that are executed :

**AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY:**
[Insert a unique occurrence of each code entered in HABITATS_POLY (from the fields: EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, and EUNIS_4) into the GESTION_CODE table (and other columns not important here)]

```
    CREATE TRIGGER A_insert_eunis_gest AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO GESTION_CODES (EUNIS, LIB_PHYSIO, Visibilite)
    SELECT DISTINCT EUNIS, LIB_PHYSIO, Visibilite
    FROM (
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_1 AS EUNIS, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_2, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_3, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_4, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
    ) AS merged_data
    WHERE EUNIS IS NOT NULL
        AND EUNIS NOT IN (SELECT EUNIS FROM GESTION_CODES);
END;
```

**AFTER INSERT ON GESTION_CODES:**
[For every feature in the "EUNIS" field, a corresponding "EUNIS22" code is searched in the BD_EUNIS22 database.]

```
CREATE TRIGGER C_search_eunis22
AFTER INSERT ON GESTION_CODES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM BD_EUNIS22
    WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS
    LIMIT 2;

    UPDATE GESTION_CODES
    SET "EUNIS22" =
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS) = 1 THEN (SELECT "Habitat EUNIS22" FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS)
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS) = 0 THEN '-'            
        ELSE '[Multiple]'
        END,
        CHOIX_EUNIS22 = 
            CASE
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS) > 1 THEN 'Voir liste'
            END
    WHERE EUNIS = NEW.EUNIS;
END;
```

**AFTER UPDATING EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES:**
[Once the codes have been updated in GESTION_CODES, they are transferred back to their respective columns (EUNIS22_1, EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3 or EUNIS22_4 in HABITATS_POLY.]

```
CREATE TRIGGER G_rapat_eunis_to_eunis22_updt 
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES 
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 
UPDATE HABITATS_POLY 
SET
        "EUNIS22_1" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1" AND "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_2" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2" AND "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_3" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3" AND "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_4" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4" AND "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL), "-");

END
```

**AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY:**
[Update again the fields EUNIS22, this turned out to be necessary to ensure that all the features were properly updated]

```
CREATE TRIGGER B_rapat_eunis22_insert
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET 
        "EUNIS22_1" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1" AND "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_2" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2" AND "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_3" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3" AND "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_4" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4" AND "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL), "-");
END;
```

**What solution could I implement to improve this process ?**

*I believe utilizing a VIEW might not be practical since BD_EUNIS22 and GESTION_CODES cannot be downsized.
In VBA, I'm used to working with virtual temporary tables. Perhaps there's a way (and a necessity) to implement a similar approach here? Both layers, HABITATS_POLY and GESTION_CODES, are operational layers actively used by the user.
I have indexed the following columns : EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3 and EUNIS_4 on HABITATS_POLY. And column EUNIS on GESTION_CODES.*

EDIT1: Some changes to the code, to add conditions to WHERE, and remove CASE. Without improvements on the performances.

---

**EDIT2: Here is the trigger I am testing (with different small changes). But it didn't improve the process.**

```
    CREATE TRIGGER B_rapat_eunis22_insert
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN

UPDATE HABITATS_POLY 
SET
    "EUNIS22_1" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(gc1."EUNIS22", "-") ELSE NULL END,
    "EUNIS22_2" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(gc2."EUNIS22", "-") ELSE NULL END,
    "EUNIS22_3" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(gc3."EUNIS22", "-") ELSE NULL END,
    "EUNIS22_4" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(gc4."EUNIS22", "-") ELSE NULL END
FROM GESTION_CODES AS gc1
LEFT JOIN GESTION_CODES AS gc2 ON gc2."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2"
LEFT JOIN GESTION_CODES AS gc3 ON gc3."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3"
LEFT JOIN GESTION_CODES AS gc4 ON gc4."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4"
    WHERE
        (gc1."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1" AND "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL) OR 
        (gc2."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2" AND "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL) OR 
        (gc3."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3" AND "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL) OR 
        (gc4."EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4" AND "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL);
END;
```

**EDIT3: Here is how the sequence of triggers works:**

[image: Process sequence]

Comment: Edit2: The triggers B and G are the ones slowering the process. I tried another way, but it didn't improve. Code presented in EDIT2, on the post.

Comment: Have barely used triggers in sqlite, so not sure if it is a good idea or if it even works. Nonetheless, I would try to replace the `.... IS NOT NULL` filters with `habitats_poly.rowid = NEW.rowid` for both slow triggers. This should explicitly update only the new row, which is the idea anyway I think.

Comment: Great ! Thank you ! I've been working on it since weeks... I remember removing "WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;" thinking that I didn't need it because of the row I insert are already new. But it prevents from searching again and again on this same row when a second one is added, etc. (If I understand well).    Well now it is all instantly done !       But... this lead to another issue, all the first new row have their EUNIS22 field populated with "-", because the correspondence in GESTION_CODES, doesn't exist yet. A few adjustments to come.

Comment: In general it is significantly faster if you can use a UNIQUE index and filtering on a value is typically also faster than on IS NOT NULL...

Comment: I am using a composite index for EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3 and EUNIS_4. Is this what you mean? For now, I don't see any alternative to using 'IS NOT NULL' since, in the case of a NULL value, the result should differ from that when no result is found. I will look for another way and update my answer if I find something good.

Comment: No, I mean that the rowid is an INTEGER column with a UNIQUE index and a NOT NULL constraint. This type of column is the fastest column you can query on. This is why `WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid` is a lot faster than using `... IS NOT NULL`. So if the updates are still slow it is better to rewrite that trigger as well to use that construct.

Comment: Hmm... I read the triggers too shallowly previously... I interpreted that the `IS NOT NULL` was there to only update the rows that were not filled out yet, but that is not the case. So all rows are/were being checked and possibly updated for each row being inserted/updated, which explains the very bad performance. The solution is the same though... Add a filter on `rowid = new.rowid` in the WHERE of the update statement in the trigger so it can efficiently filter and only the row being inserted/updated is updated.

Comment: Currently, the trigger G is the one that is slowering the most my process. For this one, I didn't specify WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid. If I do so, the update is not properly done.

Comment: I edited my first post to add a picture that shows how the sequence of triggers works. Maybe I can improve this sequence, to make sure that I can use WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid. So for now, when the first code EUNIS22 is searched from GESTION_CODES, the operation return "-" because it has not been searched yet in GESTION_CODES, after that the other occurrences of same codes are properly found, because the correspondence has been searched. I might need a better sequence, but all my attempts didn't work for now.

Comment: I'm currently dealing with an issue that has two potential solutions: 

[1] Updating EUNIS22_x (HABITATS_POLY) from EUNIS22 (GESTION_CODES) after the update of EUNIS22 on GESTION_CODES. While this approach leads to faster calculations, it comes with the drawback that the first occurrence of each code is not found. This happens because EUNIS22_x is searched before EUNIS22 has been searched on GESTION_CODES. Consequently, the first occurrence is not located initially, but the second occurrence is found afterward, as the first occurrence has already been searched.

Comment: [2] Updating EUNIS22_x (HABITATS_POLY) from the database after an insert on HABITATS_POLY. Although this method works for all features, it is noticeably slower.

Comment: Also, I can't update EUNIS22_x through "C_search_eunis22" when EUNIS22 has been calculated on GESTION_CODE. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Finaly found it. I regrouped all the triggers and I worked with rowid and pkuid.

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_insert_eunis_gest AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    -- Insérer dans GESTION_CODES les lignes distinctes de EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4
    INSERT INTO GESTION_CODES (EUNIS, LIB_PHYSIO, Visibilite)
    SELECT DISTINCT EUNIS, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
    FROM (
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_1 AS EUNIS, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite WHERE NEW.EUNIS_1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_2, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite WHERE NEW.EUNIS_2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_3, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite WHERE NEW.EUNIS_3 IS NOT NULL
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_4, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite WHERE NEW.EUNIS_4 IS NOT NULL
    ) AS merged_data
    WHERE 
        merged_data.EUNIS IS NOT NULL AND 
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE EUNIS = merged_data.EUNIS);

    -- Mettre à jour les champs EUNIS22, CHOIX_EUNIS22 dans GESTION_CODES
    UPDATE GESTION_CODES
    SET 
        "EUNIS22" =
            CASE
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = GESTION_CODES.EUNIS) = 1 THEN (SELECT "Habitat EUNIS22" FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = GESTION_CODES.EUNIS)
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = GESTION_CODES.EUNIS) = 0 THEN '-'            
                ELSE '[Multiple]'
            END,
        
        "CHOIX_EUNIS22" = 
            CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = GESTION_CODES.EUNIS) > 1 THEN 'Voir liste' END
    WHERE 
        GESTION_CODES.EUNIS IS NOT NULL AND 
        GESTION_CODES.rowid = last_insert_rowid();

    -- Mettre à jour les champs EUNIS22 dans HABITATS_POLY
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET 
        "EUNIS22_1" = CASE WHEN NEW.EUNIS_1 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT G.EUNIS22 FROM GESTION_CODES G WHERE G.EUNIS = NEW.EUNIS_1), "-") END,
        "EUNIS22_2" = CASE WHEN NEW.EUNIS_2 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT G.EUNIS22 FROM GESTION_CODES G WHERE G.EUNIS = NEW.EUNIS_2), "-") END,
        "EUNIS22_3" = CASE WHEN NEW.EUNIS_3 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT G.EUNIS22 FROM GESTION_CODES G WHERE G.EUNIS = NEW.EUNIS_3), "-") END,
        "EUNIS22_4" = CASE WHEN NEW.EUNIS_4 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT G.EUNIS22 FROM GESTION_CODES G WHERE G.EUNIS = NEW.EUNIS_4), "-") END

    WHERE 
        HABITATS_POLY.pkuid = NEW.pkuid;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the final triggers, after changes suggested by Pieter and adjustments to make sure every row is properly updated. The process is way faster (11 seconds for 1000 features)

```
    CREATE TRIGGER A_insert_eunis_gest AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO GESTION_CODES (EUNIS, LIB_PHYSIO, Visibilite)
    SELECT DISTINCT EUNIS, LIB_PHYSIO, Visibilite
    FROM (
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_1 AS EUNIS, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_2, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_3, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
        UNION
        SELECT NEW.EUNIS_4, NEW.LIB_PHYSIO, NEW.Visibilite
    ) AS merged_data
    WHERE EUNIS IS NOT NULL
        AND EUNIS NOT IN (SELECT EUNIS FROM GESTION_CODES);
END;
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER C_search_eunis22
AFTER INSERT ON GESTION_CODES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM BD_EUNIS22
    WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS
    LIMIT 2;

    UPDATE GESTION_CODES
    SET "EUNIS22" =
        CASE
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS) = 1 THEN (SELECT "Habitat EUNIS22" FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS)
            WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS) = 0 THEN '-'            
        ELSE '[Multiple]'
        END,
        CHOIX_EUNIS22 = 
            CASE
                WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BD_EUNIS22 WHERE "Habitat EUNIS12" = NEW.EUNIS) > 1 THEN 'Voir liste'
            END
        WHERE EUNIS = NEW.EUNIS;
    END;
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER G_rapat_eunis_to_eunis22_updt
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET 
        "EUNIS22_1" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1"), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_2" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2"), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_3" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3"), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_4" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4"), "-")
    WHERE 
        "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL AND "EUNIS22_1" <> COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1"), "-")
        AND "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL AND "EUNIS22_2" <> COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2"), "-")
        AND "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL AND "EUNIS22_3" <> COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3"), "-")
        AND "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL AND "EUNIS22_4" <> COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4"), "-");
END;
```

---

```
CREATE TRIGGER B_rapat_eunis22_insert
AFTER INSERT ON HABITATS_POLY
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET 
        "EUNIS22_1" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1"), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_2" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2"), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_3" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3"), "-"),
        "EUNIS22_4" = COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4"), "-")

WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid
      AND 
      (
        "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL OR
        "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL OR
        "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL OR
        "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL);
END;
```